# Heavy api call in react native slow

Tags: javascript, rest, web, react-native

I have a heavy api call (i.e one that uses a lot of data) in my react native in the `componentDidMount()` function. The issue is that it causes the whole app to become sluggish.

```js
componentDidMount() {
      fetch(HEAVY_CALL)
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(responseJSON => {
         var txs = [];
         responseJSON.result.forEach(transaction => {
         this.setState({
           transactions: txs,
         });
       });
    });
  }
```

For now I have just commented it for development purposes but I will need it in the future. Is there anyway of overcoming this?

The obvious thing to do would be to ask for less data, but this is essential to the app. I display the list of transactions later in my render method:

```js
render() {
    var sections = [
      //More sections
      { data: [{ value: this.state.transactions, type: 'transactions',}], title: 'Transactions'}
    ];
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <ScrollView>
          <SectionList
            style={styles.container}
            renderItem={this._renderItem}
            renderSectionHeader={this._renderSectionHeader}
            stickySectionHeadersEnabled={true}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
            ListHeaderComponent={this._renderListHeader}
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            sections={sections}
          />
          </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is the request going to an API that you built or to some third-party API? If it's you who built it, then simply add pagination. If not, I am pretty sure that your third party has an API for pagination.

Comment: Ah ok, good idea thanks :)

Comment: Also, Just food for thought, I have heard bad things about RN's Fetch. Have you tried using a different package like Axios or Superagent? 
That being said, +1 for pagination!

Answer (score 1):

You are setting state at every forEach step. You should push your data to txt array at every step and at the end you should set the state.

Comment: +1 - while this *shouldn't* matter because React is supposed to merge multiple `setState` calls into a single update, the process of doing so can be pretty slow, so merging them yourself manually can be beneficial.